# How to define an android permission in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I am currently trying to develop a Firemonkey application in Delphi XE8 that will have to read some barcodes. It works thanks to the part on the 75E (that correspond to the version of the Honeywell device that I have to use) from this forum:

[Consuming a 3rd Party Android API (Honeywell Datacapture.jar)](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=205636)

But I do not know where nor how to define this line in Delphi:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.honeywell.decode.permission.DECODE" />
```

It has nothing to do with the project options, and I found nothing interesting on the Internet.

Comment: DId you go into Project > Deploymend and edited manually the Android Manifest file?

Comment: I tried, but it is rewrite at each deployment...

Comment: When you build a project the android manifest is being rewritten. After the build, go into Project > Deployment and edit the manifest file. Then click the deploy button above.

Comment: The build creates everything, the deployment is the final part in which you can add/remove stuff. GIve it a try and let me know!

Comment: [Customizing Your Android Manifest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment#Customizing_Your_AndroidManifest.xml_File)

Comment: It is working, thanks both of you !

Comment: @Manon Did you build, edit the manifest and then deployed? :)

Comment: @Alberto I added the line in the AndroidManifest.template.xml and then it is automatically created in the AndroidManifest.xml of the debug folder.

Comment: @Manon, could you share your solution please? Especially related to the link which you gave.  I tried to use Honeywell scanner but I failed.